# Object to byte array to string and back

Tags: c#, string, exception, arrays, converters

I have a specific requirement to convert an object to a byte array and then to a string. Then I need to restore from string back to byte array and then to object.

I am able to perform every step except for the last one. I keep getting the following exception.
"Object must implement IConvertible."

The object is actually very small in terms of data.

Here is the code used:

```
private Object ToSafeObjectFromString(String SafeString,Type ObjectType)
{
    //This line throws the exception
    byte[] BufferArray = Convert.FromBase64String(SafeString);
    return Convert.ChangeType(CustomByteArrayToObject(BufferArray), ObjectType);
}

public static object CustomByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
    memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
    memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    object obj = (object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
    return obj;
}
private String ToSafeStringFromObject(Object Object)
{
    byte[] ByteArray = ObjectToByteArray(Object);
    String ReturnValue = Convert.ToBase64String(ByteArray);
    return ReturnValue;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use ASCII in serialization, UTF8 in deserialization ?

Comment: You have some strange usage of encoding which is likely problem . Consider using standard approach instead: Object -> Bytes -> Base64 -> Byte -> Object.

Comment: I have changed the code to Convert.ToBase64.

Comment: What is now your error ? Still OutOfMem ? Can you post the code used to test this ?

Comment: What is `ObjectToByteArray`? Can you post your full (relevant) code?

Answer (score 4):

You are using ASCII encoding for the serialization, but UTF-8 encoding for the deserialization, that looks asymmetrical.

**Do not use text encodings for binary serialization**, this has undefined behavior: the binary array you are using has no encoding at all, it is binary data.

As suggested in the comments, Use [Convert.ToBase64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) :

> Converts an array of 8-bit unsigned integers to its equivalent string representation that is encoded with base-64 digits.

And its reciprocal [Convert.FromBase64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) :

> Converts the specified string, which encodes binary data as base-64 digits, to an equivalent 8-bit unsigned integer array.

Comment: I have corrected the code based on your suggestion but now I am dealing with a different issue. "Object must implement IConvertible."

Comment: Well, the question still says "An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'", which apparently is no longer the case - it makes it really difficult to answer if some part of the question do not match the others - thus I asked for the update.

Answer (score 0):

This now works by changing this function(ToSafeObjectFromString) .

```
    public Object ToSafeObjectFromString(String SafeString, Type ObjectType)
    {
        var tmp = Convert.FromBase64String(SafeString);

        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();

        memStream.Write(tmp, 0, tmp.Length);
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        object obj = (object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);

        return obj;
    }
```